# Positioning a Custom TableView in a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-tablelayout

In my Main Activity i have a relativeLayout to which i am dynamically adding a Custom class called IconTray which `Extends TableLayout` seen below.  The IconTray takes an ArrayList and builds the table.  after the table is all built and imageViews have been placed, I want to position the table to be center Screen.  My question is, how do i position the IconTray and do i do it from the main activity or from with in itself.

**My MainActivity:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HomeFavesActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnLongClickListener{

    private static final String TAG = "HomeFavesCatovoty";
    private ArrayList<Integer> mIcons = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);



        Log.v(TAG, "CREATED");

        DataBaseManager db = new DataBaseManager(this);
        db.getWritableDatabase();
        db.AddHomeScreenIcon(1);
        db.AddHomeScreenIcon(2);
        db.AddHomeScreenIcon(3);
        /*db.AddHomeScreenIcon(4);
        db.AddHomeScreenIcon(5);
        db.AddHomeScreenIcon(6);
        db.AddHomeScreenIcon(7);*/

        getScreenIcons(db);


    }

    private void getScreenIcons(DataBaseManager db){
        mIcons = db.getHomeScreenIcons();
        Log.v(TAG, "List Length:"+  mIcons.size());

        IconTray iconTray = new IconTray(this, mIcons, null);
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        int screenWidth = metrics.heightPixels;
        int screenHeight =metrics.widthPixels;

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        iconTray.setLayoutParams(params);
        rl.addView(iconTray);


    }


    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "woot", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

}
```

**My layout xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
         >

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from your HomeFavesActivity. Right before you call rl.addView(iconTray) in the getScreenIcons method, add code that looks like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(someWidth, someHeight);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
iconTray.setLayoutParams(params);
```

You may have to play with this a little depending on how you want the height and width of the icon tray to work, but this should get you on the right track.

Comment: Im a little confused as this doesn't seem to be centering it vertically or horizontal.  It does seem to move it along the width a bit, but it is putting the table in the same x position no matter how many icons i put in the table..  i edited my main activity above..

Comment: I'd start by setting the width of the relative layout in your XML file to "match_parent". That will cause the width of the relative layout to fill the screen, which in turn should cause the icon tray to center at least horizontally. Give that a shot and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I ended up handling it in my Custom TableLayout class with a bit more control..

this.setY(screenWidth/2 - TH/2 -240);
this.setX(screenHeight/2 - TW/2 -40 );